# PasteSpecial twice crashes Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, crash, copy, copy-paste

I've been looking for a solution to using .PasteSpecial more than once in a an excel vba macro.
I have reports that can sometimes have thousands of rows. In these reports are two columns, I need to merge these columns so that if one column has blanks, I want the value from the second column; otherwise, just keep the value in the first column. I need to apply this twice in two different places. This is all tucked into a larger code.

My solution is to utilize .PasteSpecial with "Skip Blanks". It is quick for excel to process, much faster than looping row by row. The problem is that the code keeps crashing excel.

After debugging, here is what I've learned so far:
*The first .PasteSpecial always works, but when it gets to the second .PasteSpecial it always fails.
*I've tried STOP after the first .PasteSpecial then step through the code, and after I step through the second.PasteSpecial the code works just fine.
*If I step through the second .PasteSpecial it works like nothing is wrong - but if I just run the code like normal it crashes.
*I switched the order of the two .PasteSpecials within the code. When I do this, it no longer crashes on the problematic .PasteSpecial, but it does crash on the originally working .PasteSpecial.

Based on this, I know the problem is Excel doesn't like .PasteSpecial twice in a code. Still cannot find a work around. I've tried emptying the clip board, and I don't know enough how to set up an array let alone if that is efficient for this much data. Anybody know of a solution or work around?

Here is my .PasteSpecial code:

```
MainSheet.Range("N:N").Copy
MainSheet.Range("P:P").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

MainSheet.Range("R:R").Copy
MainSheet.Range("Q:Q").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: What happens if you try to Copy / PasteSpecial manually?

Comment: Have you tried putting `Application.CutCopyMode=False` between the two copy/paste operations?

Comment: Do you need copying the format, too?

Comment: If I try to do it manually it works just fine.
I tried Application.CutCopyMode=False and it still crashes.
I don't need the formatting too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

A better answer that worked more reliably than my original found solution is below. This is an adaptation of some advice from FaneDuru's answer. This solution is more taxing on resources; however, for now - it performs the task reliably (without crashing). I would love for there to be a better answers than row looping; however, this does answer my OP. Thank you for all the help!

```
    Sub copyColumnsArray()
 Dim lastR As Long, arrCopy
 
 lastR = MainSheet.Range("N" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 arrCopy = MainSheet.Range("N1:N" & lastR).value 

Dim ArrayIndex as Variant
Dim RowCount as String
RowCount = 1

For Each ArrayIndex in arrCopy
  If ArrayIndex = "" then
    RowCount = RowCount +1
    'Skip Blank
   else
    MainSheet.Range("P"+RowCount).value = ArrayIndex
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
   end if
 Next
 

 lastR = MainSheet.Range("R" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 arrCopy = MainSheet.Range("R1:R" & lastR).value

RowCount = 1

For Each ArrayIndex in arrCopy
  If ArrayIndex = "" then
    RowCount = RowCount +1
    'Skip Blank
   else
    MainSheet.Range("Q"+RowCount).value = ArrayIndex
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
   end if
 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks to be a matter of Excel necessary resources, which tried pasting before the previous pasting process finished. It is not a normal behavior, VBA should wait by itself until the operation finishes. A better solution should be using arrays, which do not involve the clipboard at all and consumes much less Excel resources. I posted a piece of code able to replace yours, being more stable and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Not needing format, please test the next code. It uses an array, not uses clipboard and is faster. If no need to exist a correspondence between the rows in the two filled columns, you can use the next fast way:

```
Sub copyColumnsArray()
 Dim lastR As Long, arrCopy, arrFin, i As Long, k As Long
 
 lastR = MainSheet.Range("N" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 arr = MainSheet.Range("N1:N" & lastR).value
 
 'fill another array only with non empty values:__________________
 ReDim arrFin(UBound(arr) To 1): k = 1
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrCopy)
    If arrCopy(i, 1) <> "" Then arrFin(k, 1) = arrCopy(i, 1): k = k + 1
 Next i
 ReDim Preserve arrFin(k - 1 To 1)
 '______________________________________________________
 
 MainSheet.Range("P1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).value = arrFin
 
 lastR = MainSheet.Range("R" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 arr = MainSheet.Range("R1:R" & lastR).value
 
 'fill another array only with non empty values:__________________
 ReDim arrFin(UBound(arr) To 1): k = 1
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrCopy)
    If arrCopy(i, 1) <> "" Then arrFin(k, 1) = arrCopy(i, 1): k = k + 1
 Next i
 ReDim Preserve arrFin(k - 1 To 1)
 '______________________________________________________
 
 MainSheet.Range("Q1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).value = arrFin
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thxs for the answer, but it doesn't work. After getting the code to run, it fills in blanks from the first column into the second column. To elaborate my goal: reason why I am using .PasteSpecial is to "Skip the Blanks" so that if there are any blanks in the first column, and there is text in the second column (same row) it will NOT erase the second column's text. However, if both have text, the first column's text overrides the second column's text.

Comment: @Steven Please, try the updated code. I used (by mistake) `arr`,  not even declared, instead of `arrCopy`. I initially tested the code using `arr` and then I thought that using `arrCopy` will be more elocvent... Using `SkipBlanks` in consecutive steps, may create problems if the empty cells does not exist on the same row...

Comment: I did notice the arr and arrCopy disconnect - I figured that is probably what you meant, so no worries. I think the issue with using the array method is that when it builds the array it places a "" inside the corresponding indexs, so when it changes the value of the second column, it places the "" everytime instead of skipping the blank. I am trying to play with ideas like "If the value if arrCopy = "" then 'skip else ..." Can you help the code so that it skips entering the array value if it is a blank?

Comment: I found a solution and entered it into your post so I can mark it as the correct answer. After the edit gets approved I'll mark it as a correct answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Steven If necessary to skip the empty cells, I will adapt the code but not like you tried. Te most time and resource consuming happens when you paste a value to a cell. if the correlation between the two columns rows does not matter, I will create a second array to receive only not empty cells and drop its content **at once**.

Comment: @Steven Please, test the updated code. Try it against your suggestion. If a big range is involved, a clear difference in favor of my variant can be observed. Please, test it and send some  feedback.

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, Thanks for the adaptation. I agree, I would much rather drop all the information at once. Correlation between the two column rows is necessary since there is other data associated with the columns. Also, there are times when both columns are blank and in those instances the row should still remain (i.e. not skipped).

Comment: @Steven If there are other column, how to skip empty rows and demolish the consistence of all data? Even if both new columns rows may be empty... This is what I have in mind when proposed the previous version. Can you tell me how to be the best processing way, from your point of view?

Comment: @Steven So, what solution do you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are committing CPU to do OS level tasks when you don't actually need to paste anything.

The cells have values... so make them Equal and they... will... be...

```
Range("C1").Value = Range("A1").Value
```

Alternatively you can use a power query to just do this where Table 2 Col2 is null and ID = ID

Comment: Hi, thxs for the answer, but this doesn't accomplish what my goal is. To elaborate my goal: reason why I am using .PasteSpecial is to "Skip the Blanks" so that if there are any blanks in the first column, and there is text in the second column (same row) it will NOT erase the second column's text. However, if both have text, the first column's text overrides the second column's text.