# PasteSpecial method of Range class failed when pasting HTML - Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, runtime-error, clipboard

I am trying to paste HTML code in a table using the clipboard. Basically, what I do is copying the text in HTML format, then I replace some tags so all the content of each cell stays in the same cell when pasted and finally I use a DataObject to put the HTML in the clipboard and paste it in the table as unicode text. The code is shown below:

```
Private Sub pasteHTMLCell()

Dim celda As Excel.Range
Dim objData As DataObject
Dim sHTML As String
 
sHTML = ""
'Loop on each of the rows of the "MyTable" table located in "MyWorkSheet" sheet for the "MyColumn" column
'to get the HTML code
For Each celda In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MyWorkSheet").ListObjects("MyTable").ListColumns("MyColumn").DataBodyRange.Cells
    sHTML = sHTML & celda.Text
    'Replace the tags that will cause the content to paste in multiple cells
    sHTML = Replace(sHTML, "<div", "<span")
    sHTML = Replace(sHTML, "</div>", "</span>")
    sHTML = Replace(sHTML, "<p", "<span")
    sHTML = Replace(sHTML, "</p>", "</span>")
    sHTML = Replace(sHTML, "<ul>", "")
    sHTML = Replace(sHTML, "</ul>", "")
    sHTML = Replace(sHTML, "<li>", "<br>" & Chr(149) & " ")
    sHTML = Replace(sHTML, "</li>", "")
    'Set the final HTML code for each cell
    sHTML = "<html><table><tr><td><style>br{mso-data-placement:same-cell;}</style>" & sHTML & "</td></tr></table>"
Next
'Use an DataObject to set the HTML and put the formatted content in the clipboard
Set objData = New DataObject
objData.SetText sHTML
objData.PutInClipboard
'Select the first row of desired column in the table
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MyWorkSheet").ListObjects("MyTable").ListColumns("MyColumn").DataBodyRange.Rows(1).Select
'This line works in debug mode but fails if I run it directly
Selection.PasteSpecial
```

End Sub

The above code runs smoothly if I use the vba debugger but always fails with a "Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error" if I execute it directly.

Any ideas why this happens? Help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: How about with `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyWorkSheet").ListObjects("MyTable").ListColumns("MyColumn").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial` instead of those current last two lines?

Comment: Still the same result. The code breaks in that line and I get the run-time error 1004 with the same message included above. Funny thing is that when I select "Debug" right after getting the error and trace the execution using F8, the code completes successfully...

Comment: Could you make a minimal example we could reproduce by providing a few of the appropriate cell entries for that column? Those entries should be sufficient that if we run the code we get the same error. You can paste a table into the question using the table insert functionality via [edit] toolbar. Alter/Remove any sensitive info.

Comment: When using the vba debugger, are you single-stepping through the code, or do you have a few breakpoints that you pause at?  Have you tried setting a few breakpoints at strategic points?

Comment: It completes successfully in both cases, inserting a breakpoint and then tracing it with the F8, or even when I select "Debug" right after the code breaks and I use the F8 to trace. When I execute the code directly, it always breaks.

Comment: You could try adding a delay - see a recent question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68473484/)